# Inconsistent rendering of identical code between IIS Express (locally) and IIS 7.5 (server)

Tags: utf-8, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I'm having a strange problem where I've got identical code in my local development machine running VS 2013 with IIS Express and my development server running IIS 7.5. It used to work fine but recently odd things started happening on my local machine. I saved off the rendered HTML output and noticed there was a small section of the layout code that didn't get rendered. I also noticed that the htm file from the server saved as ANSI and the HTML file from my local machine saved as UTF-8 BOM.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Clearly, the code (plus configuration and data) are not identical.

Comment: And, BTW, neither IIS nor IIS Express are rendering anything. ASP.NET _is_

Comment: Based on your comments, I ran a binary comparison using Beyond Compare of all files in the site directory. They are identical except for the .log files. They are both pulling from the same database. Site specific configuration (i.e. web.config) is identical so the best I can figure is it's a server level thing which is why I brought up IIS 7.5 and IIS Express.

Comment: Are they both  using identical versions of .NET? Same patches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally discovered this was caused by Visual Studios browser link functionality and to fix it we needed to disable it by putting this in the  section of the web.config:

> ```
> <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
> ```

Alternatively you can disable in in Visual Studio altogether.

More info: http://www.telerik.com/forums/the-new-browser-link-feature-in-vs-2013-is-causing-an-error-when-detailtable-of-hierarchy-radgrid-is-expanded